# HandsonTable - How to use the "IF" Formula from RuleJS

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am trying to replicate the below IF Formula from excel to handsontable but i am getting *!value*.

```
=IF(B1=0,(B5*D4),C1*D2)
```

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/15ydb2h9/

Please help me with the syntax to use it in handsontable(if possible with the jsfiddle link to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have something to do with cell C1 being a string value, which causes an error when it's multiplied.  I changed line 8 to this and it worked fine:

```
 [2012, '=SUM(A2:A5)', '=IF(B1=0,(B5*D4),C2*D2)', '=A2/B2', 12, 4151]
```